# remote subdomain URL masking

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, url-masking

Second magento based question here, and i'm pretty confident i'll be able to find my answer. What i have is a site already hosted at:

**hostedwebsite.com**

However, the host doesn't support innodb, so i'm unable to run magento on it. Because of this, the subdomain...

**shop.hostedwebsite.com**

...is now set up in CNAME and A record to point to the ip of my own host. Things on my hosts site are sorted as well. Everything loads exactly as planned. However it's keeping the base file structure from my server. So if you type in the shop subdomain you go to the right page, but it gives the url...

**myserver.com/work/newshop**

... instead of the subdomain.

I've had a go at trying to figure this out myself, i even checked with the support for the main domain and hosting, however they couldn't figure it out either and said i should try a .htaccess file with custom code. However i thought i'd ask here, as you guys will probably know a lot better than me.

Am i going about this right? IS there a way to mask the url so that it shows the shop subdomain?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you so invested in running an ecommerce website off a hosting service that isn't even capable of running Magento? Time over, this is proven to be a recipe for disaster as Magento is very resource intensive and runs best when everything is "under the same roof" on servers optimized for this.

Comment: It's my clients current hosting service, and they have already paid for the next 2 years on their hosting. Currently they are using joomla for cms and there was a zencart in a subdirectory for their old shop. Both use the same template as to try and mask that it's two different pieces of software, but it doesn't do it well at all. I was tasked with building a new shop, and as i'm magento savvy and know it's quite a powerful piece of software, it made sense to run it remotely rather than have the client waste their money.

Answer (score 0):

Check your store configuration in System > Configuration on the General / Web tab. The store URLs should be pointed to the sub domain. You could also check in the core_config_data table in MySQL and change the URLs manually.

Comment: It indeed seems that the core_config_data table was the way to go about it. Changing it in the system configuration cause me to 404 all over the place, and i went into it and found an entry still causing the issue. I appreciate the help. Thank you very much. I'd upvote if i could.