# URL masking with MAGENTO

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Is there any way of url masking with Magento.

For Eg :

Main website :

> www.magento.com

another domain :

> subdomain.magento.com

Now when i open www.magento.com website is masked/redirect to subdomain.magento.com with all the content of www.magento.com, and in URL it will display subdomain.magento.com.

let me know if this is possible in case of Magento without creating multiplestores.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19464862/remote-subdomain-url-masking i m sure that link will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :

1. Setup your URLs as “pointers” – all pointing to your Magento
   installation’s root directory
2. Navigate to your Magento Admin under System > Configuration > Web > 
   Url Options and select “No” for “Auto-redirect to Base URL”.
3. That’s it! It should work exactly how you want it to.